# Apache Tomcat : The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat9

I am new to web development .I am getting the following error for some pages when I setup a java spring MVC project in my eclipse with Tomcat server 9.0.
**The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.**

This project is working fine in another system. when I set up the same environment in my laptop and tested some of the pages I am getting the error. Initial pages are loading fine. Can anyone please help me on this? What are the things I need to check to fix this.

Comment: @[irfan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3128518/irfan): make sure, that you are using exaclty the same **version** of Tomcat.